# Converting CSV to SQLite (db file)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, csv

I have downloaded a CSV file and am trying to use it for a SQL project (I am using Jupyter notebooks). Do I even need the CSV file or is there a way to use it without downloading it? I'm very new to all of this!

This is the link to the data that I downloaded:

https://github.com/new-york-civil-liberties-union/NYPD-Misconduct-Complaint-Database

Comment: Yes you need to download data to your computer before your computer can use that data. (Your question doesn't seem to ask any other question than this)

Answer (score -1):

What's your goal? Are you trying to learn SQL, or do you just want to work with the data?

If all you want is to load that csv into a table in a SQLite database, it would be easiest to do using the sqlite command line shell.

I'm on Windows, so forgive me if you aren't...

- Open the Command Prompt
- Navigate to the folder in which you want the new sqlite db file (e.g. cd C:\Users\User\Data)
- sqlite3 NewDBName.db (e.g. sqlite3 MyNewDb.db)
- .mode csv
- .import path/to/downloaded/csv.csv NewTableName (e.g. .import C:\Users\User\Downloads\CCRB_database_raw.csv CCRB

That should be it. You can check it worked by running `.schema`- you should see the structure of your new tables.

Now you can try out some sql statements:

```
SELECT * FROM CCRB LIMIT 10;
```

[Here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/) are some more detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. I am trying to both learn SQL and work with this specific data. I have a MacBook, so I think I'll have to use the solution that you linked. Thank you for your help!